# Unable to create oauth client ID (google developer console)

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I am including sign in via google functionality in my app, for which i had created oauth client id keys for both of my debug and release mode, but since everything was not working properly so, i thought of deleting and re-creating it again, so i deleted both the keys but now when i trying to create the new keys it gives me error  as

```
 Duplicate fingerprint

The fingerprint you specified is already used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project
```

but i had deleted both the key's, i had tried all the solution that are already present in stack overflow, like going into the old console portal etc. but none is helping me out,please help me with the issue

Comment: Same issue here!! Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to go to your API console and **UNDELETE** your old projects? When you delete a project in the API console, the oauth IDs associated with it seems to not get deleted with it. I undeleted every single one and went through them and removed all associated APIs. Once I cleared out the past projects, I re-deleted them and added the oauth again to my new/safe project and it was OK.

Your problem seems to be little different, so you can look for different solutions here, as it's a common problem:
https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=554

Comment: thanx for you response, the problem is this is my only project in console where i had kept google as a login, so i dnt have any old projects ,in this project only i had added the key for the first time then deleted it now i  cannot add it